# Rscript as.formula() can't work ~!

Tags: php, r, ubuntu

I'm new in php and R. My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.

I use php to Run Rscript

## php code :

```
exec("Rscript my_rscript.R $checkbox_input $checkbox_output");
```

## Rscript code:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
len <- length(args)
all=matrix(0,1,len)
for(i in 1:len)
{
  all[1,i]=args[i]
}
goal=args[len]    
mydata <- read.csv("/home/user/normdata.csv",header=T)     
mydata <- mydata[,c(all)]    
n = names(mydata)    
temp1=paste(n[!n %in% goal],collapse = " + ")    
temp2=paste(goal,"~",temp1)    
write.table(temp2,file="/home/user/temp2.txt")   
temp3 <-as.formula(temp2)    
write.table(temp3,file="/home/user/temp3.txt")
```

It work fine on the terminal,but I need to run it through php,
Because I want to let user choose their input value,
So how do I fix this problem??
 (  It will fail at temp3 <-as.formula(temp2) ,Maybe rscript can't use as.formula()  ??)

Comment: Have the script print `goal`, `temp1` and `temp2`. I suspect some arguments are not being passed correctly or are of the wrong type/length.

Comment: There is my temp2.txt
"x"
"1" "Energy.kWh. ~ Passengers + Escalator + Temperature" 


but when set temp3 <-as.formula(temp2)   it will do noting...
even use this case below (on the buttom at the page)
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/formula.html

xnam <- paste0("x", 1:25)
fmla <- as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+")))

nothing happened ~!

Comment: Now I know problem is
write.table(temp3,file="/home/user/temp3.txt")-----


Error at as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""formula"" to a data.frame
Calls: write.table ... data.frame -> as.data.frame -> as.data.frame.default
Stop

Comment: Doh, didn't see it earlier. You're trying to write a formula object like it was a data.frame. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes,Because I  want to use that formula object in packages.(neuralnet).

like this ------------------------------------------net <- neuralnet(formula=temp3,data=mydata,hidden=10,threshold=0.01)
And temp3 is Energy.kWh. ~ Passengers + Escalator + Temperature .
No matter what  Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: If you want to save the actual formula object, consider using `save`. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html